# How do I change the app icon in the running app in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

I have an app in which I want to be able to upload a picture which is then used as the app icon. The same goes for the app name, I want to be able to change the name of the app (or at least the name that is displayed on the device) inside of the **running** app.

I tried to look this up but only found how to change the app icon in the `pubspec.yaml` and how to change the app name with a command in the terminal but not in the running app.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.